# Where to go messages after ssh from one server to another

Tags: shell

I have a c shell script , which is on server A. Then it ssh server B, tar, zip files, scp it on server A.
Can somebody let me know

1. Before ssh to B I open log file on A. After ssh to B will I be able to write messages on server A log file?
2. After scp file from B to A will I be able to ssh back to server A and untar file?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can write in A's local copy of the log file
   2.just quit the SSH to B and you're back on server A